# if...else if...else statement not working as intended

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm trying to achieve something extremely simple but it seems impossible (at least the way I want it). Basically, I've got a HTML file with an image that I want to change to a different one every time I click on a button. I've got 4 images in total and the initial image in the HTML file is "1.jpg". The problem is, I can only change the initial "1.jpg" to "2.jpg" and any further attempts to change "2.jpg" to "3.jpg" and so on fail.

Here's the code

```
function changepicture() {  
   var a = ["1.jpg" , "2.jpg" , "3.jpg" , "4.jpg"];       
   if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[0])
   {
        document.getElementById('img1').src=a[1];
   }    
   else if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[1])
   {
       document.getElementById('img1').src=a[2];
   }    
   else if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[2])
   {
       document.getElementById('img1').src=a[3];
   }
   else
   { 
       document.getElementById('img1').src=a[0]; 
   }   
}
```

The thing is, I can get it to work if I change the code to:

```
var i=0;

function changepicture() {        
   i++;        
   if (i>3) { i=0; }        
   var a = ["1.jpg" , "2.jpg" , "3.jpg" , "4.jpg"];        
   document.getElementById('img1').src=a[i];    
}
```

But, in spite of having a working alternative, I'm still not satisfied as I am convinced the first method should also work.

Comment: Use `=` for [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), `==` for [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: changing the following:

 1) "if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[0])" to "if (document.getElementById('img1').src==a[0])"                               
 2) "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[1])" to "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src==a[1])"


 3) "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[2])" to "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src==a[2])"

actually makes things worse. After these changes I can't even switch from "1.jpg" to "2.jpg"

Maybe the editor is bugged??

Comment: It's probably falling through to `.src = a[0];` but I'd have to see the actual code. Can you perhaps create a snippet that produces that behavior?

Comment: add `alert(document.getElementById('img1').src);` to your code to see, what it contains. I assume that it is not just only `1.jpg`.

Comment: As far as the snippet goes, I would have to find out what a snippet is first, lol (might have to do with me not being a native english speaker).

Comment: Regarding the alert command, you were right, it returns the absolute path for the image, not just "1.jpg"...thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you're using = where you mean to use == or ===.

Edit: To be more clear, I mean in the parenthesis of the if statements themselves, like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('img1').src == a[0]) {
```

Double edit: I believe I found another issue.  It's in the logic of the if statements:

```
document.getElementById('img1').src
```

Doesn't just equal what's in the html, like '1.jpg'.  It returns the WHOLE url.  Check out the console logs on this quick fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/71t4axv0/1/

First, it'll complain about that image not really being an image.  Then you can see the actual logic: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/2.jpg', of course, does not equal 2.jpg

Comment: changing the following: 1) "if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[0])" to "if (document.getElementById('img1').src==a[0])" 2) "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[1])" to "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src==a[1])" 3) "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[2])" to "else if (document.getElementById('img1').src==a[2])" actually makes things worse. After these changes I can't even switch from "1.jpg" to "2.jpg" Maybe the editor is bugged?? –

Comment: Hold on, I just figured out the problem.  It's because ().src returns the FULL url for the image.  I'm going to edit my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.getElementById('img1').src=a[0]) {
    document.getElementById('img1').src=a[1];
}
```

This particular statement of must have `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` / `==` typo that has been addressed by the other answers. Here, I'll address the second version of the function, where it seems you attempted to implement it as a loop. You'd have to write it like this:

```
function changepicture() {
    var a = ["1.jpg" , "2.jpg" , "3.jpg" , "4.jpg"];
    var element = document.getElementById('img1');
    var src = element.src.split('/').pop(); // get filename
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (src == a[i]) {
            element.src = a[i + 1];
            return; // stop evaluating now
        }
    }

    element.src = a[0];
}
```

<sup>**Note**: as a work around to the issue that *holl* pointed out about using the `.src` property, I use `.src.split('/').pop()` to get just the filename. This works, but an alternate solution would be to use the full paths in your array instead.</sup>

If you prefer, you can simplify this by using the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method and the [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_(.25)) operator:

```
function changepicture() {
    var a = ["1.jpg" , "2.jpg" , "3.jpg" , "4.jpg"];
    var element = document.getElementById('img1');
    var curIndex = a.indexOf(element.src.split('/').pop());
    element.src = a[(curIndex + 1) % a.length];
}
```

Here's a modified snippet that demonstrates the basic behavior (just with text, not images):

```js
    function changepicture() {
        var a = ["1.jpg" , "2.jpg" , "3.jpg" , "4.jpg"];
        var element = document.getElementById('demo');
        var curIndex = a.indexOf(element.innerText);
        element.innerText = a[(curIndex + 1) % a.length];
    }
```

```css
#demo { width: 40px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 5px }
```

```html
<div id="demo">1.jpg</div>
<button onclick="changepicture()">change</button>
```